# Statistics and Probability- probability of getting 3 heads in a row

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

in a sequence of 4 coin flips, what is the probability of getting three heads in a row?

I am stuck on this question. I understand that there are 16 possible outcomes because of the rule: "For any of K mutually exclusive events and N trials, there are KN distinct sequences (orders)." And, although I understand that there are 3 sequences where three heads in a row can occur, I want to know how to calculate this mathematically. I don't want to have to write out every possible sequence and count how many times I see three heads in a row. I want to know how to find this number with an equation. I tried the following equation: factorial(16) / factorial(3) * factorial(16-3) but this gave me the wrong answer.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Not sure what you are after.  To count the strings of length $n$ without $HHH$, all the number $a_n$, note that a (sufficiently long) string  in $a_n$ must begin with one of $T, HT, HHT$.  That gives you a simple recursion.  There really isn't a good closed form.  That said, $n=4$ is so small that it's far easier to do it by inspection.

Comment: lol extremely wrong  even. Take the factorial of 4 instead. But you want them in a row anyway so that's different

Comment: You’ve already got the ingredients. How many distinct outcomes are possible from flipping each of a penny, a nickel, a dime, and a quarter exactly one time? How many of those outcomes are wins, in other words, how many feature any consecutive three of the coins’ all coming up heads? And how do these two things together suffice for computing the probability you seek?

Comment: HHHT and THHH and perhaps HHHH seem to have "three heads in a row". I suspect HTHH and HHTH do not count.

Answer (score 0):

There are only two ways you do get 3 heads in a row, if just the last throw is tails or if just the first throw is tails. Out of the $2^4=16$ possibilities, those account for only 2 of them, so they have probability $2/16=1/8$ of occurring.